# Cannot instantiate the type PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-pageradapter, fragmentstatepageradapter, pageviews

I am working with fragments and `pageview` trying to use a horizontal pager and i got the following error:

```
Cannot instantiate the type PagerAdapter.
```

I know that `PagerAdapter` is an abstract class, so i created a new class that inherits from `PagerAdapter` and used that instead.
But didn't fix it.

that's my code:

main activity import

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
//import com.example.prova.PagerAdapter;
//import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
```

Main Activity where i have the error when i try to create a pageradapter

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    private ViewPager mPager;
    PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter; 
    //mPager.setCurrentItem(2);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // creating fragments and adding to list
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Timeline.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Postit.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Frase.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Impostazioni.class.getName()));

     // creating adapter and linking to view pager
        this.mPagerAdapter=new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments); //I GOT HERE THE ERROR
        mPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    }
```

And here my PagerAdapter

```
public abstract class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

   // fragments to instantiate in the viewpager
   private List<Fragment> fragments;

   // constructor
   public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,List<Fragment> fragments) {
      super(fm);
      this.fragments = fragments;
   }

   // return access to fragment from position, required override
   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return this.fragments.get(position);
   }

   // number of fragments in list, required override
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
      return this.fragments.size();
   }

}
```

Comment: You have your class as `abstract`.

Comment: OMG how stupid i am!! thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an instance of an abstract class.